# Keep info in the Array

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a quick question regarding to store info in the NSArray. Once I click on navigationcontroller button to go previous viewcontroller and come back myArray becomes all nil. How should I keep my original info in the array.

I have two views, one of them is tableViewController, second one is detailviewController.

Lets say user clicks on the first row, it takes user to detailviewcontroller and then user taps on the button and value increments and I save the data how many times user tapped on the button and save it storeData[0]= counter;

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably in the lifetime of the viewcontroller: When popping the controller it gets deallocated. When pushing the controller you create a new instance of the controller class which never had the array set.

It would be best to keep a strong reference to the view controller that holds the array and push the existing instance when present.

Edit: In the table view controller (master view controller) add an ivar or property of type of your detail view controller. When pushing, there are two options:

1. If the property is set, push the controller from the property.
2. Build a new controller only if the property is nil. Set the property to the new controller and push it.

Comment: That is new for me in terms of ios :)

Comment: How am I supposed to implement strong reference to viewController? could you please look at my updated question.